# Elastic Map Reduce: difference between CANCEL_AND_WAIT and CONTINUE?

Tags: boto, elastic-map-reduce, amazon-emr

I just found that using Amazon's Elastic Map Reduce, I can specify a step to have one of three ActionOnFailure choices:

- TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW
- CANCEL_AND_WAIT
- CONTINUE

TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW is the default and obvious - it shuts down the entire cluster upon a failure in the step.

What is the difference between CANCEL_AND_WAIT and CONTINUE? It appears to me that both will keep the cluster running and simply move on to the next step when it is added.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Say you have launched a cluster and added following 3 steps to it:

- Step1
- Step2
- Step3

Now, if `Step1` has ActionOnFailure as `CANCEL_AND_WAIT`, then in the event on failure of `Step1`, it would cancel all the remaining steps and the cluster will get into a `Waiting` status. And I guess if you laucng your cluster with `--stay-alive` option then this is the default behaviour.

if `Step1` has ActionOnFailure as `CONTINUE`, then in the event on failure of `Step1`, it would *continue* with the execution of `Step2`.

if `Step1` has ActionOnFailure as `TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW`, then in the event on failure of `Step1`, it would shut down the cluster as you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks! That totally makes sense - its the same for me then, since in boto I only add new steps after the previous one completes, so CANCEL_AND_WAIT and CONTINUE are the same from my perspective.

Comment: I *think* that even with --stay-alive, TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW is the default option. I've launched several stay-alive clusters, and they all terminate when one of the steps fails.

Comment: It doesn't happen that way for me, all the added steps gets into 'CANCELLED' status and cluster is in 'Waiting'. Perhaps there is something we are missing here.

Comment: That is very very interesting. Maybe boto makes TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW the default? In any case, thanks for your answer!

Comment: Also the `Instances.KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps` configuration plays a role here. If set to `True`, cluster will __WAIT__ after executing (`ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE`)  or cancelling (`ActionOnFailure=CANCEL_AND_WAIT`) steps 2 and 3. When set to `False`, cluster will __TERMINATE__ after executing or cancelling steps 2 and 3.